# NewBe Joomla 1.7 Templeates with SQL

Tags: joomla

I have a standard joomla template in a new cateragy and articale
in C:\x\htdocs\templates\beez_20\ that I have copyied over and renamed

I want to retian the log in ...... down the left hand side of the page
but I want to write a database driven content in the main part of my page
a) Do I use my Index file and were in the index can i include a PHP file for my database content.
b) Is thier any soical rules I need to know about in adding feilds to tables in Joomla.
c) How Do I get the user of this page at that time when the user is using it.

Lex Dean.

Answer (score 0):

a) You should not have to hard code anything in to index.php ever. You should use the module manager to assign modules to the various pages within the site

b) You should absolutely not touch any database table as this will cause problems with updating either core Joomla or extensions. If you need to store data, then you need to write an extension to handle the data in a new table.

c) `$user =& JFactory::getUser();`

You should really take a look at some of the Joomla tutorials before you get too far in to your project. Understanding how Joomla uses index.php, templates, over rides, and modules will make your Joomla experience a much better one.

Comment: Thanks for advice, This is not what I've not been told before.   I Do not know properly about modles and will explorer more.

Comment: Just to reinforce what Brent said - take the time to figure out why Joomla is a 'menu driven' site, and look at the tutorials - specifically on 'displaying an article', or 'setting up a menu', this will help you tremendously and save you wasting time hand-coding something into the core that will be erased when you update Joomla.